# Problems with code for checking if an object has more then 5 children and if so destroying the 5th child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I am trying to check the amount of children a `Transform` has and if the number of children exceed 5 delete the fifth child. I do this using a method which is called every frame in the update method.

This is my code:

```
void ChildrenCheck(){
    if (transform.childCount > 4) {
            GameObject child = transform.GetChild (5).gameObject;
            Destroy (child);
    }
}
```

However, when the there are more then 5 children instead of deleting the fifth child I get this error:

```
UnityException: Transform child out of bounds
KillFeed.ChildrenCheck () (at Assets/Scripts/KillFeed.cs:21)
KillFeed.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/KillFeed.cs:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function Transform.GetChild() requires an index and not its position. Therefor there are no children at index 5, only at 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4.

To fix your error, try Transform.GetChild(4).gameobject;

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html

Comment: No problem, always check the documentation on how things work if you're unsure or encounter a problem like this.